# Do redox reactions always contain pure elements?

Tags: redox

According to [a video by the Organic Chemistry Tutor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QyLXaPCR_s), a quite well-known chemistry channel on YouTube, you can easily identify a redox reaction by seeing if there are atoms in their elemental states on one side of a reaction and form compounds (or compounds decomposing to elemental atoms) on the other. Is this accurate?

Comment: Not quite. True, all such reactions are redox. But not all (and not even most) redox reactions are like this.

Comment: Do not try to learn chemistry via moronic youtube videos. You can be sure they are going to tell you some supersimplyfied nonsense, which breaks the  second you try to use it on sth else.

Comment: Counterexample : K+Na -> NaK https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium-potassium_alloy

Comment: The problem is that until you have learned a good deal of chemistry, you can't tell moronic videos from the good ones. Ditto for teachers and textbooks.

Comment: Some textbooks are however *known* to be good. I wouldn't say the same about youtube channels. ;-)

Comment: @Karl Then again, maybe some youtube channels are also known to be good, just not to you or me? I'd rather give them a benefit of the doubt. (I don't watch any, and don't plan to anytime soon.)

Comment: @IvanNeretin Neither do I. ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to leave this open. It's based on a common guideline for identifying redox and the misinterpretations that surround it. Perfectly valid question IMO, and not homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a redox reaction that does not contain any zero-valent atom:

$$\ce{2FeCl3 + SnCl2 + 2 HCl -> 2 FeCl2 + H2[SnCl6]}\tag{1}$$